# Regex from Python to Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have a question about Regular Expression (Regex) and I really newbie in this. I found a tutorial a Regex written in Python to delete the data and replace it with an empty string.
This is the code from Python:

```
import re

def extract_identity(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub.
    Args:
         data (dict): The dictionary with data specific to this type of event.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): The Cloud Functions event
         metadata.
    """
    import base64
    import json
    import urllib.parse
    import urllib.request

    if 'data' in data:
        strjson = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8')
        text = json.loads(strjson)
        text = text['data']['results'][0]['description']

        lines = text.split("\n")
        res = []
        for line in lines:
            line = re.sub('gol. darah|nik|kewarganegaraan|nama|status perkawinan|berlaku hingga|alamat|agama|tempat/tgl lahir|jenis kelamin|gol darah|rt/rw|kel|desa|kecamatan', '', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            line = line.replace(":","").strip()
            if line != "":
                res.append(line)

        p = {
            "province": res[0],
            "city": res[1],
            "id": res[2],
            "name": res[3],
            "birthdate": res[4],
        }

        print('Information extracted:{}'.format(p))
```

In the above function, information extraction is done by removing all e-KTP labels with regular expressions.

This is the sample of e-KTP:
[image]

And this is the result after scanning that e-KTP using the python code:

```
Information extracted:{'province': 'PROVINSI JAWA TIMUR', 'city': 'KABUPATEN BANYUWANGI', 'id': '351024300b730004', 'name': 'TUHAN', 'birthdate': 'BANYUWANGI, 30-06-1973'}
```

This is the full tutorial from the above [code](https://medium.com/@imrenagi/ekstraksi-informasi-e-ktp-dengan-google-cloud-function-dan-cloud-vision-api-4655db21d084).

And then my question is, can we use Regex in Kotlin to remove the label from the result of e-KTP like in python code? Because I try some logic that I understand it does not remove the label of e-KTP. My code in Kotlin like this:

```
....

        val lines = result.text.split("\n")
        val res = mutableListOf<String>()
        Log.e("TAG LIST STRING", lines.toString())
        for (line in lines) {
            Log.e("TAG STRING", line)
            line.matches(Regex("gol. darah|nik|kewarganegaraan|nama|status perkawinan|berlaku hingga|alamat|agama|tempat/tgl lahir|jenis kelamin|gol darah|rt/rw|kel|desa|kecamatan"))
            line.replace(":","")

            if (line != "") {
                res.add(line)
            }
            Log.e("TAG RES", res.toString())

        }
        Log.e("TAG INSERT", res.toString())
        tvProvinsi.text = res[0]
        tvKota.text = res[1]
        tvNIK.text = res[2]
        tvNama.text = res[3]
        tvTgl.text = res[4]

        ....
```

And this is the result of my code:

```
TAG LIST STRING: [PROVINSI JAWA BARAP, KABUPATEN TASIKMALAYA, NIK 320625XXXXXXXXXX, BRiEAFAUZEROMARA, Nama, TempatTgiLahir, Jenis keiamir, etc]

TAG INSERT: [PROVINSI JAWA BARAP, KABUPATEN TASIKMALAYA, NIK 320625XXXXXXXXXX, BRiEAFAUZEROMARA, Nama, TempatTgiLahir, Jenis keiamir, etc]
```

The label still exists, It's possible to remove a label using Regex or something in Kotlin like in Python?

Comment: The question is "too broad", you need to narrow it down to 1) what string / type of string you have, 2) what you need to get.

Comment: I just want to remove a label using Regex after scanning the e-KTP like in the python, it's possible to do that in Kotlin?

Comment: What is a label? Where is it in a string? What does it look like?

Comment: If you see the image (e-KTP/Card) that I attached above. In the card have "NIK :, Name :, Tampat/Tgl Lahir, etc" It's mean a label. In the python code above, after scanning the Card, the result is remove the label (the results on the left include a sign :) because he using Regex in python `line = re.sub('gol. darah|nik|kewarganegaraan|...)`. So in the Kotlin it's possible to do that?

Comment: FYI, for I get the String from scanning the Card and show the result as a String, I using Firebase ML Kit

Comment: If you plan to only port the `re.sub` to Kotlin, use `line = line.replace(Regex("""(?i)gol\. darah|nik|kewarganegaraan|nama|status perkawinan|berlaku hingga|alamat|agama|tempat/tgl lahir|jenis kelamin|gol darah|rt/rw|kel|desa|kecamatan"""), "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to use [`kotlin.text.replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) with a `Regex` as the search argument. For example:

```
text = text.replace(Regex("""<REGEX_PATTERN_HERE>"""), "<REPLACEMENT_STRING_HERE>")
```

You may use

```
line = line.replace(Regex("""(?i)gol\. darah|nik|kewarganegaraan|nama|status perkawinan|berlaku hingga|alamat|agama|tempat/tgl lahir|jenis kelamin|gol darah|rt/rw|kel|desa|kecamatan"""), "")
```

Note that `(?i)` at the start of the pattern is a quick way to make the whole pattern case insensitive.

Also, when you need to match a `.` with a regex you need to escape it. Since a backslash can be coded in several ways and people often fail to do it correctly, it is always recommended to define regex patterns within *raw* string literals, in Kotlin, you may use the triple-double-quoted string literals, i.e. `"""..."""` where each `\` is treated as a literal backslash that is used to form *regex escapes*.